# Limit to infinity of a quotient of two functions, whose limits are known

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the following,
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = L $$ 
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = \infty $$
prove that
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0 $$
using the definition of limits

I understand the definitions of all of the limits above. Just need help on how to link the definition of first two limits in order to prove the last one!

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, find some $m>0$ such that $x\geq m$, we have $|f(x)-L|<1$ and $g(x)>\dfrac{|L|+1}{\epsilon}$, then for such $x$, we have $\left|\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|\leq\dfrac{|L|+1}{(|L|+1)\epsilon^{-1}}=\epsilon$.

Comment: and to get from $ |f(x)-L| < 1$ to $|f(x)| < |L| + 1 $ we use the triangle inequality?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Ah alright. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, it is no need to adjust $(|L|+1)/\epsilon$ to get the final inequality ends with such clean way, that is, if we let $g(x)>1/\epsilon$, we get $|f(x)/g(x)|\leq(|L|+1)\epsilon$, this will work as well, because $|L|+1$ is a positive number that does not depend on $x$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Don't we have to show that there is a positive real $M$ such that if $x>M$ then $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: The $M$ that you stated is just the little $m$ that I wrote. Yes, such $m$ must be found to let $|f(x)/g(x)|<\epsilon$ in traditional way. But what if the $m$ you found satisfies only $|f(x)/g(x)|<2\epsilon$, is this a correct proof? Yes, it is, can you figure out why?

Comment: Would it be right to say that since $\epsilon$ was chosen arbitrarily, $2\epsilon$ would also be arbitrary and we can set $\epsilon' = 2\epsilon$ and still arrive at some expression for $m$ in terms of $\epsilon'$ which would satisfy $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| < \epsilon'$?

And if the above was a correct proof would it be right to say for any positive real $k$, any proof that produces  $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}| < k\epsilon$ is valid?

Comment: You almost get the point. To elaborate more, for suppose we have the ending with $2\epsilon$, now, given $\eta>0$, consider the positive number $\eta/2$, we have some $m$ such that ...$<2(\eta/2)=\eta$.

Comment: Yes, so it is no need to adjust dual $\epsilon/2$ inequalities to get $\epsilon$ at the end (remember how to prove $f(x)+g(x)\rightarrow L+M$?), just feel free to do many lines of $\epsilon$ inequalities to end up with some positive number multiplied with $\epsilon$. To clarify more, whenever the ending is some sort of $P(\epsilon)$ such that $P(\epsilon)$ itself tends to $0$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, the argument is valid. So with $2\epsilon$ is fine, $\epsilon^{2}$ is fine, $\epsilon^{2}(\epsilon+1)$ is fine, but $\epsilon+1$ is no good.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is interesting. The way I was taught in my undergraduate calculus class didn't go into this reasoning.
For $f(x)+g(x)\rightarrow L+M$, we studied the proof involving the dual $\epsilon/2$  inequalities.
So in a sense, if we wind up with an expression $P(\epsilon)$ such that $P(\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, our generating function for $m$, say $m(\epsilon)$ would still be able to produce a valid answer?